# .draggable() bug, page scrolls automatically

Tags: draggable, autoscroll

I have included a draggable div on the website that I am building (visible here: gongle.fr), it is a kind of business card that is present on all pages.

However, when I drag it in either Chrome or Safari it causes the whole page to scroll down automatically, and regardless of the direction I am dragging in.

Strangely, on the the single project pages there is not this problem, so I guess it must be solvable in my mark up, but I have no idea how to do it.

Can anybody help?